# Show two random posts from custom post type

Tags: wp-query, loop

I've set the code below to show info from the latest two posts of a custom post type (it also loops through and adds a class of first to alternate items for layout purposes). How would I amend this to show two random posts?

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom_advert', 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
echo '<div class="sixcol ';
if ( $counter % 2 == 1 ) { echo 'first'; }
echo '"><a href="[using custom meta to get link address here]"><img src="[using custom meta to show image here]"></a></div>';
$counter++;
endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need an [`orderby` argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'custom_advert', 
  'posts_per_page' => 2,
  'orderby' => 'rand'
);
```

That should pull posts in a random order and stop after retrieving the first two, hence two random posts.

Comment: Is this 'computationally' expensive if you have several thousands of posts? I mean the random ordering.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster : WordPress uses MySQL's `RAND()` for this and that is never really an efficient operator, but if that is what you need, that is what you need. There are some rather complex attempts at a "better" `RAND` if you search around but I have never seen the benefit.

Comment: I made a plugin using this code: https://wordpress.org/plugins/load-random-post/